# Why do web frameworks serve via FastCGI/SCGI, rather than HTTP?

Tags: django, http, fastcgi, scgi

Major web frameworks (such as Django, Pyramid, Rails, etc) are often run as persistent servers, with a separate web server like nginx serving as a frontend. The web server connects via a protocol like FastCGI or SCGI:

```
browser --[http]--> nginx --[fastcgi]--> flup -> django
```

This seems convoluted to me; why is the request converted to an entirely different protocol, when the backend could just run its own HTTP server?

```
browser --[http]--> nginx --[http]--> wsgiref -> django
```

This approach appears to be both simpler and more flexible, since there's only one transport protocol and it's an RFC.

However, I don't think I've *ever* seen a web framework encourage the http-only design, so I assume there must be a reason for it.

What are the advantages of using a protocol like FastCGI/SCGI here?

Comment: C++/C probably outperforms those debugging servers any day. Most (all?) of those web frameworks are coded in Python or Ruby, which are interpreted languages.

Comment: @Blender: While true, that's probably not relevant. I wouldn't expect Django serving via FastCGI to be faster or slower than Django serving via HTTP. Also, neither Python nor Ruby are interpreted. They use bytecode VMs, in a manner similar to Java.

Comment: Good point. I'm beating my head against a wall getting Flask to work with Lighty... Also, nitpicking, but on the Python homepage it states `... an interpreted, interactive, object-oriented...`

Comment: Yeah; that description probably dates from when it *was* interpreted. I know 2.x compiles to bytecode, but maybe 1.x was different.

Comment: I seem to remember the Pylons/Pyramid "standard" recommended setup at least being HTTP-only with Apache or nginx as a reverse proxy as you describe here. Django's documentation, too, seems to treat the *CGIs as second-class citizens: "many people use shared hosting, on which protocols such as FastCGI, SCGI or AJP are the only viable options."

Comment: \*CGI *is* a second-class citizen in Django; it is written to WSGI, and everything else requires an adapter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTTP is a [large, complex protocol](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt). Paring the interface down to the capabilities provided by FastCGI or WSGI allows the framework to handle requests faster than if it had to deal with the original.